# Code not working (pyautogui locate on screen)

Tags: python, pyautogui

Hi I am a beginner to python and i am trying to make a program to automatically answer questions in a math game, i am using "if pyautogui.locateOnScreen" it has worked before but used random answers for random questions but now it doesnt answer any, i will provide a snippet of the code:

```
from pyautogui import * 
import pyautogui 
import time 
import keyboard 
import random
import win32api, win32con

if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('6x8.png', region=(350,240,500,95), grayscale=True, confidence=0.9) != None:
         pyautogui.write('48')
         pyautogui.press('enter')
         print("48")
         while True:
          break
          
sleep(0.01) 
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('8x6.png', region=(350,240,500,95), grayscale=True, confidence=0.9) != None:
  pyautogui.write('48')
  pyautogui.press('enter')
  print("48")
  while True:
   break
                 

sleep(0.01)
if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('88d11.png', region=(350,240,500,95), grayscale=True, confidence=0.9) != None:
    pyautogui.write('8')
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    print("8")
    while True:
     break
```

etc with all of the questions (about 400 lines)  if you know why please help

Comment: Have you tried lowering the confidence?

Comment: yes its still not answering any questions, im not sure why

Comment: Without looking at what it looked like before and after it stopped working it's a bit hard to say, but it might be due to resizing or a change in background color

Comment: Try retaking the pictures you want to locate if starts working again it means something is changing in the way they are displayed on screen

Comment: i have lowered the confidence but now it is answering wrong a lot of the time.

Comment: Confidence might be too low and now matching with unrelevant stuff

Comment: i have fixed the confidence now, but even though i have the questions in the code it is only answering the first 3 or 5, i have double checked that the code to answer those questions is there, i can provide the full code if needed (about 400 lines but most of it is just the same as what i already posted just with different questions/answers)